# C segmentation fault when using strsep/strdup to manipulate a C string into struct variables

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Me again with another segmentation fault(*groan*).

To get where i am now i have had help in other questions on here.

The idea behind this function is:

- pass in a char*
- duplicate the passed in char* onto the heap and point to this location
- use strsep to split the "string" based on the ',' delimiter
- assign these split tokens to struct variables
- free the pointers

This is what i pass to the function:

gga_sentence struct:

```
typedef struct gga_sentence{

    const char *untouched_sentence;
    gsa_sentence *gsa;
    char *sentence_id;
    int time_stamp;
    double latitude;
    char north_south_id;
    double longitude;
    char east_west_id;
    int quality;
    int no_of_satellites;
    double horizontal_dillution;
    double altitude;
    char altitude_units;
    double geodial_seperation;
    char geodial_seperation_units;
    char* age_of_data_in_seconds;
    char *checksum;

}gga_sentence;
```

gga_parsed is:

```
    gga_sentence *ggas_parsed;
    ggas_parsed = malloc(10*sizeof(gga_sentence));
```

where line is a char[100] which is filled using a line read from a file, this works fine.

```
strncpy(&ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence, line, strlen(line));
            printf("GGA UNTOUCHED: %s", &ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence);
```

initiate_gga_values(&ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed], &ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence);

The above printf statement:

```
printf("GGA UNTOUCHED: %s", &ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence);
```

produces:

```
GGA UNTOUCHED: $GPGGA,151019.000,5225.9627,N,00401.1624,W,1,09,1.0,38.9,M,51.1,M,,0000*72
```

so when i pass this to the function as described above by:

```
initiate_gga_values(&ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed], &ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence);
```

where the function itsef is defined as:

```
void initiate_gga_values(gga_sentence* gga_ptr, const char* sentence){

    char *temp_sentence, *second_temp_ptr;
    char *token;
    int token_no = 0;

    temp_sentence = strdup(sentence);
    second_temp_ptr = temp_sentence;

    printf("TS: %s", temp_sentence);
    printf("2nd: %s", second_temp_ptr);

    token = strsep (&second_temp_ptr,",");

    while (token != NULL) {
        /*if a sentence has missing data then make that clear by settings it's value to
         * <EMPTY>*/
        if(strlen(token)==0){
            token = "<EMPTY>";
        }
        switch(token_no){
        case 0:
            gga_ptr->sentence_id = token;
            //printf("%s,",gga_ptr->sentence_id);
            break;
        case 1:
            /*atoi converts a string to an int, well a c string anyways so a char* */
            gga_ptr->time_stamp = atoi(token);
            //printf("%d,",gga_ptr->time_stamp);
            break;
        case 2:
            /*strtod coverts a string to a double, well a c string anyways so a char* */
            gga_ptr->latitude = strtod(token, NULL);
            //printf("%f,",gga_ptr->latitude);
            break;
        case 3:
            gga_ptr->north_south_id = *token;
            //printf("%c,",gga_ptr->north_south_id);
            break;
        case 4:
            gga_ptr->longitude = strtod(token, NULL);
            //printf("%f,",gga_ptr->longitude);
            break;
        case 5:
            gga_ptr->east_west_id = *token;
            //printf("%c,",gga_ptr->east_west_id);
            break;
        case 6:
            gga_ptr->quality = atoi(token);
            //printf("%d,",gga_ptr->quality);
            break;
        case 7:
            gga_ptr->no_of_satellites = atoi(token);
            //printf("%d,",gga_ptr->no_of_satellites);
            break;
        case 8:
            gga_ptr->horizontal_dillution = strtod(token, NULL);
            //printf("%f,",gga_ptr->horizontal_dillution);
            break;
        case 9:
            gga_ptr->altitude = strtod(token, NULL);
            //printf("%f,",gga_ptr->altitude);
            break;
        case 10:
            gga_ptr->altitude_units = *token;
            //printf("%c,",gga_ptr->altitude_units);
            break;
        case 11:
            gga_ptr->geodial_seperation = strtod(token, NULL);
            //printf("%f,",gga_ptr->geodial_seperation);
            break;
        case 12:
            gga_ptr->geodial_seperation_units = *token;
            //printf("%c,",gga_ptr->geodial_seperation_units);
            break;
        case 13:
            /*This is never used in the sentenced given*/
            gga_ptr->age_of_data_in_seconds = token;
            //printf("%s,",gga_ptr->age_of_data_in_seconds);
            break;
        case 14:
            gga_ptr->checksum = token;
            //printf("%s",gga_ptr->checksum);
            break;
        }
        token_no++;
        token = strsep (&second_temp_ptr, ",");

    }

    printf("untouched: %s\n", sentence);
    printf("Second print of TS: %s\n", temp_sentence);
    printf("second print of second_temp: %s\n", second_temp_ptr);

    free(temp_sentence);
    exit(1); //DBUGGING PURPOSES
}
```

The output from this function is:

```
TS: $GPGGA,151019.000,5225.9627,N,00401.1624,W,1,09,1.0,38.9,M,51.1,M,,0000*72
2nd: $GPGGA,151019.000,5225.9627,N,00401.1624,W,1,09,1.0,38.9,M,51.1,M,,0000*72
untouched: $GPGGA,151019.00�(m
Second print of TS: $GPGGA
second print of second_temp: (null)
```

so if i add this printf statement:

```
printf("testing untouched: %s", gga_ptr->untouched_sentence);
```

into the initiate_gga_values function, just before the exit(1) i get a segmentation fault. The output of running the code again with the extra print line which prints a gga_ptr->untouched_sentence produces:

```
GGA UNTOUCHED: $GPGGA,151019.000,5225.9627,N,00401.1624,W,1,09,1.0,38.9,M,51.1,M,,0000*72
TS: $GPGGA,151019.000,5225.9627,N,00401.1624,W,1,09,1.0,38.9,M,51.1,M,,0000*72
2nd: $GPGGA,151019.000,5225.9627,N,00401.1624,W,1,09,1.0,38.9,M,51.1,M,,0000*72
untouched: $GPGGA,151019.00��b
Second print of TS: $GPGGA
second print of second_temp: (null)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have no idea what is going on.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: No offence, but this is your fourth question on what appears to be the same piece of code and the same kind of problem, i.e. you're getting a crash at run-time and you don't know how to debug it. Maybe it's time to work on your debugging skills, e.g. learn to use gdb, how to add strategic printfs, how to "divide and conquer", etc? This will pay dividends in the long run - debugging is an essential skill for anyone who wants to write code seriously/professionally.

Comment: Also I think you should start with a much simpler problem - copy the string and print it out, compile with all warnings, and run under valgrind and fix all errors.

Comment: @PaulR i have been doing that using gdb in combination with printf statements, and where/backtrace command etc. However i do not seem to be progressing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
const char* untouched_sentence;

strncpy(&ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence, line, strlen(line));
            printf("GGA UNTOUCHED: %s", &ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence);
```

The first argument to `strncpy` should be a buffer to put the copy into, you've given it a pointer into your structure. The third argument should be the size of the destination buffer, not the input!

You need to do:

```
char* untouched_sentence;

ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence = malloc(<size>);
```

Where `<size>` needs to be strlen(line) with some restriction if you are worried about long lines.

Then:

```
strncpy(ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence, line, strlen(line));
printf("GGA UNTOUCHED: %s",ggas_parsed[number_of_gga_parsed].untouched_sentence);
```

I think you need to start with a simpler example to get your head around memory management.

Comment: upvoting you for putting in the effort to slog through all that mess

Comment: thanks! i am really sorry for having terrible code, I'm trying but obviously not hard enough. Sorry.